# Why does the return from "system" not match the return of the script that was called?

Tags: c, linux, system

I have a simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# exit5.bash
exit 5
```

And I call it with system in a c program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ret = system("./exit5.bash");
    printf("%d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

And I see 1280 printed to the screen, which is the same as `5 << 8`

Why do I not see regular 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of `system` is a termination *status*, not an exit *code*.

See the [return value section of `man system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html#RETURN_VALUE):

> In the last two cases, the return value is a "wait status" that can be examined using the macros described in [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).  (i.e., `WIFEXITED()`, `WEXITSTATUS()`, and so on).

What you're looking for is returned by the `WEXITSTATUS` macro:

> `WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)`
>
> returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child specified in a call to `exit(3)` or `_exit(2)` or as the argument for a return statement in `main()`.  This macro should be employed only if `WIFEXITED` returned true.

Comment: specifically in this case you want `printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(ret));` tbc. Compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` or `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` or greater.